# Не отображаются русские буквы на странице

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, asp.net-core, .net-core

Не выводит русские буквы, хотя указал
context.Response.ContentType = "text/html;charset:utf-8";

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace LearnAspNetCore
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.Run(Hundle);

            async Task Hundle(HttpContext context)
            {
                string host = context.Request.Host.Value;
                string path = context.Request.Path; // путь запроса
                string query = context.Request.QueryString.Value; // параметры строки запроса
                context.Response.ContentType = "text/html;charset:utf-8";
                await context.Response.WriteAsync($"<h3>Хост: {host}</h3>" +
                    $"<h3>Путь запроса: {path}</h3>" +
                    $"<h3>Параметры строки запроса: {query}</h3>");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Не выводит русские буквы" - а что делает?

Comment: Непонятные символы отображает

Comment: наверно это потом что вы пишете в `Response` не utf8. Посмотрите второй ответ в [этом вопросе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722642/how-to-make-stream-write-output-in-utf-8-format)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Charset` обычно задается через `=`, а не `:` как у вас.

То есть вам достаточно заменить строку `ContentType` на `context.Response.ContentType = "text/html; charset=utf-8";`

Документация: [тык](https://www.w3.org/International/articles/http-charset/index.ru).